# How to I debug systemJS error loading js as "" from

Tags: npm, aurelia, systemjs, jspm

I am getting the following error:

```
system.src.js:123 Uncaught (in promise) Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:8000/dist/jquery.js
    Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:8000/dist/jquery.js
    Error loading http://localhost:8000/dist/jquery.js as "jquery" from http://localhost:8000/jspm_packages/npm/toastr@2.1.2/toastr.js
```

How do I go about fixing this?

I have done `npm install` and `jspm install`.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share more details like link to plunker or gistrun? According to the error, it can't find `jquery.js` is dist folder. Please check that file exist in correct location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure that `jquery` is mapped to the correct path in `node_modules` and also any modules that depend on jquery have the dependency explicitly declared:

```
map: {
  'jquery' : 'path_to_jquery'
},
meta: {
  'file_that depends_on_jquery' : {
    deps: ['jquery']
  }
}
```